# (In English) is there a way/shorthand to refer to the minutes part of a plane's landing time? (I.e. omitting the hour)

Tags: radio-communications, terminology

For example, if a plane lands at 17:34, is it possible (in English) to only report the minutes (34) portion of the time? If so, how?

The reason/context for the question: I'm trying to translate something from another language (Mandarin); the speaker is a pilot, the addressee is an air traffic controller, but the conversation is taking place off work (so not precisely radio communications); the phrasing is "我XX分落地的," roughly translated to "I landed at `xx` minutes".

Comment: Why would you even do that?  If I had to do it for some reason, I'd write "HR+15", but I don't know if there is any kind of convention. If spoken, "15 past the hour".

Comment: In your question who would you be reporting your landing time to and would you be reporting verbally or on paper?

Comment: I really think [edit]ing your question to indicate _why_ and in _what situation_ you would want to report only the minutes would be very helpful in having people understand the question and get you an appropriate answer. Seems to me that everyone is pretty confused.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you for pointing this out. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: That helps a bit. It would probably help quite a bit more if you translated the rest of the Mandarin for us. There probably aren't _too_ many here who speak it. Something like "Hey, Joe, I landed or 26L at 36 <fill in the blank> then exited on taxiway B" or whatever...

Comment: @FreeMan The Mandarin statement means something along the lines of "I landed at XX minutes," referring to the minutes part of the time when the plane landed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no value in omitting the hour for brevity or any reason, and it sort of depends on who you are reporting to, the medium, and for what purpose.

You do save a few syllables saying "thirty four past" rather than "seventeen thirty four", but this may not always be the case depending on the number.

But yes, there is a way to say it clearly without mentioning the hour as long as you are still currently within that hour.  Whether you are talking to a dispatcher or ATC on the radio to close out a flight plan after landing at a non-towered airport you can simply say "thirty four past" (as mentioned above).  I've also heard things like "landed at time three four" and "**on** at three four".

As long as your meaning is clear there shouldn't be a problem, but I am not aware of any convention or phraseology (other than a company standard) specifically for omitting the hour.

Answer (score 6):

I fly privately in Australia and whenever there is a requirement to communicate a time over the radio we say "at time two-zero", which indicates 20 minutes past the current hour. If it's not the current hour we revert to UTC and say "at time zero one two zero".

We don't have to report actual landing time to anyone. Times are generally required under IFR to tell ATC of the next waypoint ETA, or to tell traffic at untowered airfields of our ETA into the circuit pattern.

The reason we speak like this is the same reason we say "heading zero one three" instead of "heading thirteen". It is clearer over the radio to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

It would simply be a **convention** for the particular report, that the landing (or Out or Off or In) time would be reported "here" using the two digits representing minutes past the hour. Those using that format would understand that "on at 36, in at 41" means XX:36 and XX:41 for the respective times.

There would have to be a way to ensure that the correct hour is eventually matched up with each time (i.e. for a case of a tarmac delay, landed at 0836 but blocked in at 0941), but there can be ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if both the air traffic controller and the pilot during this conversation knew what hour that the landing in question took place, the pilot could say something like *"I landed at "thirty four."*

If it was not clear what hour the landing took place then the entire hour and minute would have to be spoken, e.g., *"I landed at seventeen thirty four."*

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is in the wrong place, and you are looking for a linguistic answer, rather than a valid radio phraseology term...

You would say "34 minutes past the hour".

However, this is not necessarily correct radio phraseology that would be used in aviation.